# linq to list(of string) in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview

This is my Variable in my.setting

```
<Global.System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute(), _
    Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), _
    Global.System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")> _
    Public Property Name() As List(Of String)
        Get
            Return CType(Me("name"), List(Of String))
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of String))
            Me("name") = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

How do i can put it to datagridview by using linq
Tanks

Comment: You'll have to explain more what "pull into a `DataGridView`" means - just the list by itself?  Or as an additional column to an existing data source?

Comment: Have you tried just setting it directly?  `dgv.DataSource = Settings.Name`